# Buggy behavior of "Help and Improvement" review as the daily 20 tasks reached

Tags: bug

After reaching the daily maximum of 20 review tasks in the new "Help and Improvement" queue, the behavior of the GUI is problematic. There is no "Next", or "Skip" button anymore.

The screenshot was from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/helper/7324089):

[image]

I created this screenshot on Firefox, but the problem looks more likely browser-independent.

Comment: Raised earlier on MSO: [There is no Next button when reaching 20 posts on the Help & Improvement queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287815/there-is-no-next-button-when-reaching-20-posts-on-the-help-improvement-queue)

Comment: Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280497/missing-next-button-in-the-triage-queue-after-a-successful-looks-ok-review https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283062/upvote-suggestion-in-triage-queue-has-no-next-button